# How to professionaly react when you forgot a colleague's birthday?

Tags: colleagues, birthday

It is the birthday of one of my colleagues and I learned about it at almost the end of the day via LinkedIn.

As the colleague is in my working team, he must be aware that I forgot.

What is the correct work etiquette in this situation? Just wish him out of the blue or ignore it since we only know each other at work?

Comment: Does your team or your company normally celebrate birthdays in the office?

Comment: Well usually the guy has to take things from the bakery the morning for breakfast at the company and colleagues are doing funny things to the colleague's desk but it seems that no one knew it was his birthday

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The thing is I would normally do that with humor, but since he is a colleague It seems weirder, since I know him only in a professional context. I was wondering if there was some sort of professional way to do that. We only know from chats at the coffee machine really. And from the project we work on.

Comment: just a personal tip, when i forget a birthday, i usually wait for an "assist" and then say "was your birthday?HB, sorry i did not remember it, still not be able to remember what i ate yesterday", this way the fault is sort of minimized and always found that social links were not broken

Comment: @Anon We've got a pro over here

Comment: I would be really surprised if anyone in my office knew when my birthday is and a bit uncomfortable is they celebrated it.  Except in one or two cases, they are my coworkers, not my friends.  I'd be angry if someone messed up my desk.

Comment: Did you forget (knew his birthday was coming up; wanted to do something for it) or did you just not know it was his birthday? If you can make it through the entire day without getting any reminders, they probably don't really celebrate it in the office.

Comment: @Erik Well now I'm in the situation of a colleague telling him "Oh sh5164 told me that was your birthday ahah !" and me just being like a tree not knowing what to tell...

Comment: The only birthday's worthy of note are 0-13, 21, 90+ and for girls in Mexico, 15. To be put on the spot for forgetting any other birthdays should yield a "are-you-kidding-me-face".

Comment: Their birthday was obviously not important enough to them to bring in cakes/sweets etc 'for the team', so why is it your problem that you didn't find out until it was nearly over?

Comment: If your colleague by any chance is the dude who wrote this question, you've probably got a new friend: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/147305/how-do-i-stop-my-colleague-trying-to-convince-me-that-im-trans?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say it's unlikely to be a problem, in fact it's entirely possible that they aren't the sort of person who makes a big deal out of their birthday (I can relate - at both my current and previous job I never even mentioned it).

Unless they are some sort of massive prima donna type I expect you'll be fine just casually mentioning it in the morning

> Morning *X*, realised last night that it was your birthday yesterday so Happy Birthday for yesterday! did you do anything nice?

If they *are* the prima donna type then frankly that's their problem!

Comment: Also, they get to be "special" for two days instead of just one; they might appreciate your wishes even more than if you had done it on their birthday.

Answer (score 1):

I have a tough time remembering my children's birthdays. For **years** I kept mixing up March 21 with March 23.

People forget. People understand forgetting.  Aside from taking steps with a device so you won't forget in the future, you **be honest** and admit that you forgot and do what it takes to rectify it.

You're human. You forget. Everyone does.  As long as you're honest about it, you should be fine.

Comment: O no, your poor children:(